# Customizing a Tensorboard component (runs selector)

Tags: plugins, components, tensorboard, bazel

I need a custom Runs Selector component that will allow to cancel training Slurm jobs that do not look promising directly from Tensorboard. I need to add a "Cancel" button in front of every run in Runs Selector. I already figured out how to send AJAX request to the server and how to handle it in my Python script on the server.

It looks like I need to implement a plugin, copy and modify tf_runs_selector Tensorboard component and make it part of my plugin.
I tried to use greeter_plugin example as a prototype of my plugin. I copied tf_runs_selector directory from Tensorboard and put it under my plugin's directory (I renamed tf_runs_selector to my_runs_selector, and tf-runs-selector.html to my-runs-selector.html). Now I have the following directory structure:

```
~/tensorboard_plugin_example
     greeter_plugin
         BUILD
         (other files)
         my_runs_selector
               BUILD
               my-runs-selector.html
```

I replaced "tf" refix with "my" prefix in "tf_runs_selector" and "tf-runs-selector" in my_runs_selector/BUILD file, and removed

```
"@org_tensorflow_tensorboard//tensorboard/components/tf_paginated_view",
```

from greeter_plugin/BUILD file
.
Here is the contents of BUILD file in my_runs_selector subdirectory:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("//tensorboard/defs:web.bzl", "tf_web_library")

licenses(["notice"])  # Apache 2.0

tf_web_library(
    name = "my_runs_selector",
    srcs = ["my-runs-selector.html"],
    path = "/my-runs-selector",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//tensorboard/components/tf_backend",
        "//tensorboard/components/tf_color_scale",
        "//tensorboard/components/tf_dashboard_common",
        "//tensorboard/components/tf_imports:polymer",
        "@org_polymer_paper_button",
        "@org_polymer_paper_dialog",
        "@org_polymer_paper_styles",
    ],
)
```

But when I try to buikd my custom tensorboard, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: greeter_plugin/greeter-dashboard.html: Referenced my_runs_selector/my-runs-selector.html (/greeter-plugin/my_runs_selector/my-runs-selector.html) without depending on a web_library() rule providing it
NOTE: Use suppress=["strictDependencies"] to make the errors above warnings
Target //greeter_tensorboard:greeter_tensorboard failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /home/tkapustin/tensorboard-plugin-example/greeter_tensorboard/BUILD:56:1 Checking webfiles //greeter_plugin:greeter_dashboard failed (Exit 1)
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.314s, Critical Path: 0.09s, Remote (0.00% of the time): [queue: 0.00%, setup: 0.00%, process: 0.00%]
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

So my questions are:

1. How should I modify BUILD file in my_runs_selector directory?
2. How should I modify BUILD file in greeter_plugin directory?

to be able to build my plugin with a custom my_runs_selector component?